# Metric space statements

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $A, B$ and $E$ be subsets of $X$. The boundary of a subset $E$ of $X$, is denoted by $\partial E$, and is defined as $\partial E= \overline{E} \cap \overline{X-E}$. State whether or not each of the following statements is true or false. In the statement is true prove it; otherwise provide a counterexample.

(a) $(A')'=A'$

Pretty sure this is false since if $A'$ is a finite set then $(A')'=\emptyset \ne A'$.

(b) $int(\overline{A})=int(A)$

I guess it's sufficient enough to find an example where for $p\in int(\overline{A}), p\in A'$

(c) $\overline{A\cup B}=\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$

(d) $int(A\cup B)=int(A)\cup int(B)$

(e) $\overline{A\cap B} = \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$

(f) $\partial E = \partial \overline{E}$.

---

Part (c)-(f) are the ones I have problems with.
How should I approach them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For (d), (e), (f) you can find very simple counterexamples in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @kahen He's assuming $A'$ is finite, which makes the proof correct.

Comment: @roman apparently I can't read. Somehow I missed that...

Comment: no problem guys, thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, most statments of this type can be disproved using $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$, or adjacent open or closed intervals. Since most of the statements are one liners, I'll just give you them and let you prove any statements that you don't know. Also, try formalizing part (c).

(a) Consider $A=\{ 1/n|n\in \mathbb{N}\} $ then $A'={0}$ and $(A')'=\varnothing $ so $A'\neq (A')'$.

(b) Consider $A=\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\overline{A}=\mathbb{R}$. $\mathrm{int}(\mathbb{Q})=\varnothing$, but $\mathrm{int}(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$.

(c) This is true. Since the union of closed sets is a closed set, and $\overline{A}\cup \overline{B}$ contains $A\cup B$, $\overline{A}\cup \overline{B}\subseteq \overline{A\cup B}$. If $p\in\overline{A\cup B}$, then there is a sequence in $A\cup B$ that sequence that converges to $p$. The sequence contains an infinite number of terms in either $A$ or $B$ and thus in $p\in \overline{A}$ or $p\in \overline{B}$ and so $\overline{A\cup B} \subseteq \overline{A}\cup \overline{B}$ and $\overline{A\cup B}=\overline{A}\cup \overline{B}$

(d) Consider $A=[0, 1]$ and $B=[1, 2]$, then $A\cup B=[0, 2]$ so $\mathrm{int}(A\cup B)=(0, 2)$, but $\mathrm{int}(A)\cup\mathrm{int}(B)=(0, 1)\cup (1, 2)$ so $\mathrm{int}(A)\cup\mathrm{int}(B)\neq \mathrm{int}(A\cup B)

(e) Choose $A=(0, 1)$ and $B=(1, 2)$. Then $\overline{A\cap B}=\overline{\varnothing}=\varnothing$, but $\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}=\overline {\{ 1\}}=\{1 \}$, so $\overline{A\cap B}\neq \overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$

(f) Consider $E=\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\partial (E)=\mathbb{R}$ but $\partial (\overline{E})=\varnothing$, so $\partial E\neq \partial \overline{E}$

Answer (score 1):

The only statement that is true is (c).

For the rest consider $X= \mathbb{R}$ and consider sets like $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ (this won't work for (a), but you already got it).